# Matplotlib: How to unset default colormap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am showing images with matplotlib and applying some colormaps to the images. I've figured you can set a default colormap by something like

```
plt.set_cmap('jet')
```

and then that colormap will be applied every time when using `plt.imshow()`

But how about undoing that? If I want to show the original images again without any colormap? I haven't found in the docs anything about that, neither by quick googling so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "without any colormap"? If you don't set the colormap using `set_cmap('jet')` the default colormap will be applied to the images. Are you just trying get back to the matplotlib default?

Comment: @DavidG yes, my question was how get the default colormap back in case you have already set some other with `set_cmap()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the colormap using `set_cmap` as you are aware. This changes the colormap for all subsequent figures plotted. If you want to undo the changes you have made, simply go back to the matplotlib default colormap, which in matplotlib 2 is `viridis`.

However, there is also a `cmap` argument for `imshow()` which lets you change the colormap applied for an individual plot. This means you don't keep having to change the global colormap, however you *would* have to write this in every call to `imshow()`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.randn(25).reshape(5,5)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax1.imshow(data)
ax1.set_title("Matplotlib default cmap")

ax2.imshow(data, cmap='jet')
ax2.set_title("jet cmap")

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: That `viridis` was the one I was looking for! Thanks!! I was aware of the `cmap` argument in `imshow()` but didn't know this default colormap that could be set by `set_cmap()`

Comment: No problem. [This](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#colormap) shows the changes that were made to matplotlib 2 colormap default style

Answer (score 0):

The command `plt.set_cmap("jet")` sets the colormap in the rcParams to be the `"jet"` colormap.

In order to get back the default colormap, you can set the cmap to the default colormap from the `rcParamsDefault` dictionary.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(plt.rcParams["image.cmap"]) # prints viridis

plt.set_cmap("jet")
print(plt.rcParams["image.cmap"]) # prints jet

plt.set_cmap(plt.rcParamsDefault["image.cmap"])
print(plt.rcParams["image.cmap"]) # prints viridis
```